# Is there any standard oid list for all the SNMP enabled devices or is it vendor specific?

Tags: networking, snmp, oid

Is there any standard list of oid list for all the SNMP enabled devices? I want to retrieve some device information over my network for all the SNMP enabled devices.

I got something like, oid are in MIBs of individual devices. How to get all the oid list by which I can know what are the information that I can get by SNMP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is called `discovery` in the network monitoring world. The high-level approach to this is to usually ping your entire IP network graph using ICMP or TCP pings and on a response, do an SNMP get of a standard RTF OID, like `sysname`. You SNMP get a standard RTF OID because those are usually implemented by default on most systems.

1. ICMP Ping entire network elements
2. On response, do an SNMP Ping
3. On response, log the IP address as SNMP discovered

Comment: Thanks for your answer,can you give me an example how to ping the entire network and then how to ping snmp to the response.

Comment: my ip is 10.0.3.61 and my subnet addr is 255.255.248.0 so kindly tell me what to do next.